# While initialising reCAPTCHA Enterprise in ios app i'm getting unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2833a81e0 error

Tags: swift, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to integrate recaptcha enterprice sdk in my ios app, built with swift.
I followed the documentation mentioned here. https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#swift.

I have imported the recaptcha-enterprise-mobile-sdk for ios using Swift Package Manager.
the package url mentioned in the docs was https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/recaptcha-enterprise-mobile-sdk.

When i try to run this block of code.

```swift
let (recaptchaClient, error) = await Recaptcha.getClient(siteKey: key)
if let recaptchaClient = recaptchaClient {
  self.recaptchaClient = recaptchaClient
}
if let error = error {
  print("RecaptchaClient creation error: \(error.errorMessage ?? "NIL").");
}
```

I'm getting these errors,

```
2023-04-14 12:55:20.351476+0530 Runner[2442:667659] -[RCAx_GPBTimestamp initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28191c000
2023-04-14 12:55:20.352389+0530 Runner[2442:667659] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCAx_GPBTimestamp initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28191c000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cbdbba84 0x1ca20d958 0x1cbf1c110 0x1cbdd0c28 0x1cbe3470c 0x104bc3d74 0x104bbd91c 0x104bbda04 0x104b973a8 0x104a3c08c 0x104a3d8c4 0x104a44a20 0x104a45698 0x104a51158 0x218562b50 0x21856267c)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCAx_GPBTimestamp initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28191c000'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(Recorded stack frame)
```

What does this error mean? how to resolve this error?

error was thrown from this method.

```
Recaptcha.getClient(siteKey: key)
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem eventually? Because I have run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

Many probably skip this point:
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#configure_app

[Objective - C Bridging Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqowE.png)

You need

1. create an Objective-C bridging header and include the following import

To create a bridging header in your Swift project and include an import for Objective-C code, follow these steps:

1. In Xcode, create a new header file by going to File -> New -> File (or press Command+N).
2. Select "Header File" under the "Source" section and click "Next".
   Name the file "YourProjectName-Bridging-Header" (replace "YourProjectName" with the actual name of your project) and save it in your project's directory.
3. In your project's build settings, search for "Objective-C Bridging Header" and set the value to the path of your bridging header file. For example, "YourProjectName/YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h".
4. Open the bridging header file you created and import the Objective-C code by adding the following line:

#import <RecaptchaEnterprise/RecaptchaEnterprise.h>

[Simple Bridging Header file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGkV0.png)

Now you can access your Objective-C code from your Swift files. Make sure to import the necessary headers in your Objective-C file as well, if needed.

Note: If you don't see the "Objective-C Bridging Header" setting in your build settings, you may need to manually configure it by specifying the bridging header file path in the "Objective-C Bridging Header" build setting (under "Swift Compiler - General").

Remember to replace "YourProjectName" and "YourObjectiveCFile.h" with the appropriate names for your project and Objective-C file.

[Build Setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw61Z.png)

2. Ensure that -ObjC is listed on your linker flags. Navigate to Target > Build Settings > All > Linking and verify that Other Linker Flags shows -ObjC.